# Unity DotNetZip Unzip (Распаковка в оперативную память png)

Tags: c#, unity3d, zip, archive, dotnetzip

Как сделать так, что бы после распаковки в MemoryStream(Если я правильно понял, то он его извлекает в оперативную память), я мог получить Image (пытался получить Texture, но мне не подходит из-за того что нужно указывать вручную размер картинки, а картинки у меня разного размера).

АссетБандлы не подходят.

Сохранить в файл я могу, но мне нужно использовать в РеалТайме.

```
 public Sprite GetImage(string indexImage)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"D:/Unity 18.2.6/Projects/Ama_Kids/Assets/MemoricaImages.zip"))
        {
            zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;


            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
            {
                if (e.FileName.Equals(indexImage + ".png"))
                {

                    MemoryStream tempS = new MemoryStream();
                    e.Extract(tempS);

                    var tex = new Texture2D(100, 100);
                    tex.LoadImage(tempS.GetBuffer());
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(tex,Rect.zero,new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f));
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Используйте лучше lz4 компрессию, жмёт лучше и заточена для потоков, очень быстрая штука. Вообще в `C#` работа с изображениями очень не быстрая, если есть возможность, уходите в c/c++ с этими процедурами.

Comment: Не используйте `GetBuffer`. Этот метод возвращает буфер в памяти, куда записываются ваши данные, но как и любой буфер, он обычно выделяется с запасом. К примеру, у вас картинка 100 байт весит, а в памяти выделится область в 256 байт. В результате GetBuffer вернёт этот самый массив в 256 байт с нулями в конце. Вместо этого вызовите `ToArray`, который создаст копию только тех данных, которые записали. Поэтому, возможно, ваш код и не работает, потому что png изображение с дополнительными нулями не валиден. Других проблем не вижу.